# What is the limit as $x\to\infty$ of $\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry, limits, infinity

What is the limit as $x\to\infty$ of $\cos x$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the immortal words of Lindsay Lohan...

Comment: @Qiaochu: your joke eludes me. Citation please?

Comment: @Willie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIMSC-RWvF8 (skip to 7:40 for the problem and 8:10 or so for its solution).

Comment: thank you Qiaochu! Damn that was worth wasting 9 minutes of my life!

Answer (score 13):

The limit does not exist. It oscillates between -1 and 1. Just so that you know, the limit supremum or infimum as $x \to \infty$ is given as

$$\lim \sup_{x\to\infty} \cos(x) = 1$$
$$\lim \inf_{x\to\infty} \cos(x) = -1$$

Answer (score 9):

The limit does not exist because $\cos{(2\pi n)} = 1$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\cos{(\pi + 2 \pi n)} = -1$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$, since $\cos$ oscillates between -1 and 1.

A bit more detailed:
We say that a function $f(x)$ has a limit as $x \to \infty$ if there exists a real number $a$ (called the limit) such that $|f(x)-a|$ can be made arbitrarily small for all $x$ which are "large enough". "Large enough" and arbitrarily small means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we should be able to find a number $N$ such that $|f(x)-a| < \varepsilon$ for all $x > N$.

In the case of $f(x) = \cos x$ we can't do this when $\varepsilon$ is small.  Independent of which $a$ we are trying out, we can always find a large enough $x$ such that $|\cos x - a| > \frac{1}{2}$ (for example), and infinitely many of them (since $\cos$ is periodic).

As Roupam Ghosh stated in his answer, the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ for $\cos x$ as $x \to \infty$ are not equal. This gives that the limit does not exist, since then you can always find sufficiently large $x,y$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=\left|\limsup_{x \to \infty}\cos x - \liminf_{n \to \infty} \cos x\right|\geq\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the proofs given are not rigorous enough, and are not necessarily easy to understand to someone who is not familiar with the material, so I'll try a more rigorous approach. I'll assume every variable I'm referring to is a real number in `R`.

Assume that there is a limit `k`. In that case it must be that for every `d` there exist `N>0` so that if `n>N` we have that `|cos(n)-k|<d`.

Since `cos(x+n2pi)=cos(x)`, it is easy to see that for every `N` we can find a number `n0>N` for which `cos(n0)=0`, and another number `n1` for which `cos(n0)=1`. Try to prove that, it's not so hard.

Let `d=1/2`, whatever `k` would be, we'll have that either `|cos(n0)-k|=|k|>d=1/2` or `|cos(n1)-k|=|1-k|>d=1/2`.

Therefor no number is the limit of `lim`<sub>n→∞</sub>`cos(n)`. Since `cos(n)` is bounded it cannot be that the limit is `∞` or `-∞`.

Comment: Your notation is misleading. What are $n$ and $N$? Are they positive integers?

Comment: I don't quite see your point. If $a = \lim_{x \to \infty} \cos{(x)}$ existed then by definition it would be the limit of every sequence of real numbers $x_{n} \to \infty$, so it suffices to exhibit two sequences converging to different limits.

Comment: Good point! I think integer or real doesn't really matter. Tried to clarify this issue.

Comment: @Theo, my point is, (1) you have to spell out the reason like you did, and I didn't find that in the answers, (2) sometimes the TA wants the answer in an epsilon-delta form.

Comment: @Elazar: We are not being graded by a TA on this site.  You can supply a lot of detail if you like, but it is not expected that full details are spelled out in each answer, especially if the question is for homework.

Comment: @Jonas, the OP seems to be a beginner in calculus, telling him things like "cos oscillate between 1 and 0", when I'm not sure he grasped the concept of limit might confuse him, or imply him that such answer is an acceptable proof. I wasn't born with calculus book in my hand, so I think trying to help beginners in this site is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar problem:

Find all periodic functions $f$ such that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$
exists.